# C++ basic architectural design

Tags: c++, architecture

I´m not sure about the right decision so I ask the community:

So the question is: is it better to model attributes through types or through attributes or is there even a third way?

Let´s say we have two balls - red and blue and I have to do something with them.
So the first idea was:

```
    struct Ball
    {
        RGB color;
    };

    void food( Ball& ball)
    {
        if ball.color == RED ....
        if ball.color == BLUE ....
    }
```

I think you get it. But I want to get rid of the if(..) so I can changed this to

```
    struct Ball
    { 
        virtual RGB color() = 0;
    }

    struct RedBall : public Ball
    {
        RGB color() { return( RED); }
    };

    struct BlueBall : public Ball
    {
        RGB color() { return( BLUE); }
    };

    void foo( RedBall&) ...
    void foo( BlueBall&) ....
```

I´m not sure if it is the proper way by creating new types (by inheritance or by using decorators) to depict program flow and behavior because this could quickly lead to huge class hierarchies.

It becomes even worse if I think about using these types with the visitor pattern, especially for decorated types.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow.  You already have a two close votes (one "Too Broad" and one "Primarily Opinion Based").  I expect your question will be closed soon.

Comment: Polymorphism allows to alter behavior in derived classes when executing overloaded method. In your example both derived classes do exactly the same thing so inheritance is rather pointless. However if you had some sort of `DbBall` that would query its colour from some sort of database instead of getting class field value then it would be reasonable to use inheritance.

Comment: I´m trying to make it clearer: think about some sort of filter function that only collects red balls. Regualy I´m using a visitor to implement these function, therefore I have to choose either if(...) or polymorphism in the visitor to reach the goal. But I wonder if there is a better way to achiev this...
Well if Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this question, I´m sorry and hope for some hints where this could be discussed.

Comment: If your code is *readable* it is good code. If it is *unit-testable* it is great code. Be a great coder, write great code.

Answer (score 2):

To have multiple versions of `foo`, that takes different colours of `Ball` seems completely wrong. I would argue that if you want to do that, you probably want a member function within `Ball` that does whatever `foo` does differently for the different colours of ball.

You can choose to implement that as a virtual function and have derived classes to represent each colour, or have a set of if-statements which are now internal to the `Ball` class, so "hidden" for others.

The idea with object orientation is to have objects that "do stuff", not just holders of properties (colour in this case), so the "most correct" way to solve this is to have the class itself know what objects of that kind should do.

Comment: I´m not a big fan of implementing aspects such as filtering, persistence, representation etc. into an object. 
IMO this should be delegated to other objects - and then again, type matters.